# "Don't vote politically" banner

Tags: feature-request

There are many good (and mediocre) questions on this site which do not have a partisan slant to them.  But there's some which provoke voting based on the politics of the viewer rather than the quality of the question.  <sub>*(I'd appriciate if people added examples of this behavior to the bottom of this question)*</sub>

As the [meta "When should I vote FAQ" says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130054/165591):

> Do NOT downvote just because:
>
> - The question uses incorrect grammar (as long as it is comprehensible)
> - The question has bad, (but clear) code; the question uses bad coding practices; the premise of the program is wrong. In this case, just comment "why haven't you done blah?". If you're answering, you can append that to your answer instead. (I've done that here). Remember, voting is to filter post quality, not code quality or OP quality.. Also, there are legitimate uses for everything, even eval().

Skeptics has a banner which can be added to unsourced questions and answers which explicitly notes that it is original research and/or unsupported, to remind people that [original research is not generally acceptable](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/522/7280) and to edit or vote accordingly.  **I propose adding a "politically controversial" banner for the same general purpose**.

Example wording would be something like:

> This question is asking about a political subject in a controversial way and/or exhibiting a strong ideological bias.   Please vote based on the **quality of the question** and not whether you agree with the stated opinion.

<sub>I know my first pass at this sucks, but I'm hoping someone likes the idea and comes up with better wording.</sub>

Comment: Somewhat related use cases: voting down an answer to a question which amounts to "Why do the people say they do XYZ" (usually XYZ means holding a specific opinion) because you disagree with the opinion XYZ, even if the answer is factually correct on what the people holding the opinion state, and takes the pain to indicate that it's the opinion of those people and not the answerer's.

Comment: @DVK - Agreed in general, although it's very easy for that type of question to be worded in an unanswerable way (i.e. "Why do people do XYZ?" instead of "What do people say is the reason they do XYZ?")  We can't see into people's minds.

Comment: It might be easier to meaningfully discuss this issue if you had an example of where it is needed.  Is there any specific post that you believe that people voted on politically(and incorrectly)?

Comment: @Bobson - Good point! I was referring to the second kind of warning.

Comment: @SamIam - would an answer with upvotes where the OP openly admitted that the answerer wasn't even answering the question as asked qualify? :)

Comment: @DVK yes it would.

Comment: @SamIam - Here's my favorite. 3 upvotes. http://politics.stackexchange.com/a/1097/115. This is AFTER I have posted - right after it was created - that it is offtopic to the question. AND my comments were deleted by a mod as well (because my comment was followed up by political attacks)

Comment: @SamIam - for that matter, your own answer has 2 downvotes despite being reasonably reasonable. My own answer has  1 downvote despite not only being ontopic, but taking the pains to document every example of viewpoints as requested.

Comment: @DVK  Now here's the kicker:  Do you think that the people who upvoted that answer, believed that they were voting "politically"

Comment: @SamIam - I wouldn't be at all surprised if the answer is "no"

Comment: @SamIam - Honestly, I don't remember seeing any questions where a good question was voted down based on politics.  I've seen a few questions which *I* consider to be poor questions get a surprising number of upvotes.  Part of the problem might be a disagreement over what makes for a poor question, though.  ---- That being said, I have repeatedly seen the claim that this stack's users are biased one way (or the other).  I would appreciate if those making such claims provide examples.

Comment: @DVK - I was only considering questions when I posted this, but that's a nice example.  I've downvoted (since it's an off-topic answer), but I don't know whether or not voting on answers ought to be considered the same as voting on questions.  Does the many-to-one nature of answers to questions excuse voting based on personal political opinion and not objective quality?  I don't have an answer, but it's a good question to bring up...

Comment: @Bobson - if the undertaking wasn't so futile, I'd give you example of questions.

Comment: @DVK - How can we fix anything if we can't identify the problem?  How do you know it's going to be futile?  *I* haven't personally noticed this pattern, but I haven't been looking for it.  I *have* seen the claim made repeatedly by you and others, and I'm willing to accept that I just don't see it.  So either there is a problem and I can be shown it, or there isn't one and there's no reason to gripe.  Can you provide three example questions?  Or am I trying to solve a problem that doesn't actually exist?